# Customize a view of recurring calendar events using client side rendering (JSLink)

Tags: 2013, jslink, client-side-rendering

I'm trying to apply CSR to a calendar-view. This seems not to be working.
In fact the file specified in `JSLink` is not loaded at all.

As a basis I'm using the standard "Current Events"-view which shows recurring events by default.

It does this by showing a `XsltListViewWebPart` whose attributes show `ServerRender="False" ClientRender="False"` and a view whose attributes show `RecurrenceRowset="TRUE"`.

I'm guessing the `ClientRender="False"` attribute is the reason why the `JSLink` is not used at all. However it seems impossible to set `ClientRender="True"` when `RecurrenceRowset="TRUE"` is set at the same time.

Setting `RecurrenceRowset="False"` enables me to set `ClientRender="True"` and makes the `JSLink` work perfect. But that way I'm losing the recurring events.

Is there a "nice" way to show recurring events from a calendar in a view while customizing it using CSR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having struggled with this quite a bit I feel there is no real solution!

Setting `RecurrenceRowset="TRUE"` on a view seems to imply `ClientRender="False"`- though I can not find any source on that.

The only nice way (for me) seems to be to skip using the default calendar view at all and add a nice custom page and load the calendar entries using CSOM.
(Or try out [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) whose `GetListItems` operation seems to be able to set `<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>` in the caml-query)

Comment: I was just running into the same problem, and this is very disappointing to hear.  Nice to know that SPServices might be able to help push the processing/calculating of recurring events back onto SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

One of the very common reason for jsLink not loading is that you have specified incorrect path in the jsLink property.

The way i prefer to do it put alert on the JSLink and make sure that alert comes up in the list view,  that indicates that our link is pointing to the right JSLink file.

I usually store all my jsLink files on the Site Assets library (js folder) of the site collection and my path looks something like below:-

```
~sitecollection/SiteAssets/JS/jslinkfilename.js
```

Similarly if you have stored it in the current web you will be using:

```
~site/SiteAssets/js/jslinkfilename.js
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote: If I set `RecurrenceRowset="False"` on the view I am able to set `ClientRender="True"` on the `XsltListViewWebPart` and this makes my JSLink load an reder perfectly fine. So neither path nor content of the JSLink are the problem.