# Using CSR to change row color - how do I keep the view style shaded view?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Using  CSR to change row color - how do I keep the view style shaded view ?

It seems the CSR in a CEWP only works if I keep the view style on default.

How do I keep the code working but have the view style remain in shaded view?

My code is below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
            var CategoryColors = { 'Training': '#6699ff', };
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var Category = rows[i]["Category"];
                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                row.style.backgroundColor = CategoryColors[Category];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the view style to target in your template override.  I'm guessing you have code that looks something like:

```
var viewOverrides = {};
viewOverrides.Templates = {};
viewOverrides.Templates.Header = // something
viewOverrides.Templates.Item = //something
viewOverrides.Templates.Footer = // something

// here's what you need to add
viewOverrides.ViewStyle = 17;  // I believe 17 is the ID of Shaded, but you may need to check on that
```

Here is the most comprehensive source of information on CSR for list views that I have been able to find (*much* better than what you can find on MSDN):

[Andrei Markeev - SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

**Edit:**

Ok, based on your code, you would need to add the `ViewStyle` specification like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
            var CategoryColors = { 'Training': '#6699ff', };
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var Category = rows[i]["Category"];
                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                row.style.backgroundColor = CategoryColors[Category];
            }
        },
        ViewStyle: 17
    });
});
```

Again, just to be clear, I am guessing that the ID of the "Shaded" view style is 17 only based off the screen shot in the CodeProject article I linked to.  I do not have any first-hand knowledge that that is the correct ID, so you might want to double check that.

Comment: Hello. My code is like this.

Comment: SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
      var CategoryColors =  {
          'Training': '#6699ff',  
       };               
       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var Category = rows[i]["Category"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = CategoryColors[Category];
       }
     }
   }); 
});

Comment: My code is like above - how to make it so that "shaded" stays the same except for the rows that equal the category training. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeRooker, updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Dylan, however adding that just didn't make any rows change color at all as well as not making it shaded.

Comment: Ok, sorry it didn't help.  I do not have any experience with view styles, but based on what is available as options for CSR, that seemed like the way to go.  Maybe read through the article I linked to and see if it gives you any ideas.

Comment: Quick question though -- what view style were you using when you added the code and you say it didn't work?  You need to set the view style to shaded in the normal way, the code addition will not force the view style to be shaded.  What the code does is say "if the view style is shaded, then apply these template overrides."  If you were set to the default view style, then of course it did not apply the color change, because by specifying `ViewStyle: 17` then the custom code no longer applies to the default view style.

Comment: Thank you Dylan. I have tried both "default" and "shaded" styles. Is there a way to perhaps add that the CAML statement on the page via SharePoint Designer 2013?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  I played around a bit and I could not get it working either.  It's possible that the view style is doing something that prevents it from being overridden, similar to [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/109642/8992).  Is there some other functionality of the "Shaded" view style that you want to have, other than having alternating rows have a grey background color?  If not, you can just set alternating rows background color to grey on the default view through your override.